# ATMega32 C++ Object in Timer Interrupt

Tags: c++, c, embedded, interrupt, avr

Is there a possibility to call a member function, say the output over UART, to be triggered by an interrupt?
Normally I would have used the TIMER0_COMP vect but I can't seem to get it to work with objects.

Comment: C++ code is not always safe in an interrupt.  I recommend using pure C for interrupts unless you know C++ well enough that you can translate it to assembly in your head.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Can you provide some information about what risks you see using C++ in interrupts?  I have not come across any language-specific problems versus C in a number of years of embedded development.

Comment: @Ross: C++ makes it easy to hide library calls in code by accident.  Few library calls are interrupt-safe.  C is more explicit.  As always, experts can do what they want.

Comment: @DietrichEpp:  C++ is by no means as unpredictable as you make it sound.  And why would you need to "translate to assembly in your head"!? You can observe the disassembly in your debugger or get the compiler to output an assembler listing if you need to check the code generation.

Answer (score 2):

```
SomeClass theObject;

// ...

ISR(USART_RX_vect)
{
   theObject.someMethod();
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, that, or some variant of it, is about all you can do since interrupt handlers have no context - something has to be global/static.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to have an interrupt vector point to a specific **object's** member function.  This is due to the fact that it is not possible to pass the *this pointer to an ISR directly.

It is possible to have the interrupt vector point to a specific **class's** member function, provided that it is a static function that returns void and has no parameters.  However, as it's a static function it has no access to any individual object's non-static data members.

Here's an example for an IAR compiler and a timer interrupt vector from an AVR:

```
class theClass
{
  public:
  ...

  #pragma vector=TCC1_CCA_vect
  __interrupt static void isrTimer1CompareA(void);

  ...
 }
```

Again, the limitations with this approach are that the ISR can only access static data for the class.

If you're looking to have the interrupt to relate to a specific object, you'll need something along the lines of what H2C03 recommends, which is having the ISR know about the specific object, then calling a member of that object in the ISR itself.